# Mocking final class with parameterized constructor

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a final class as below

```
public  class firstclass{

   private String firstmethod(){

       return new secondclass("params").somemethod();

}

}


public final class secondclass{

   secondclass(String params){

        //some code

}

public String somemethod(){

         // some code 
        return somevariable";
}
}
```

I have to here test first class so I have mocked this as below

```
secondclass classMock = PowerMockito.mock(secondclass .class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(secondclass .class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(classMock);
Mockito.doReturn("test").when(classMock).somemethod();
```

But it is not mocking as I expected can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would you mock a final class?  If it's final, it's not meant to be used that way.

Comment: I have to test firstclass firstmethod. In that there is a call for secondclass somemethod which returns somevariable so I mocked that to return test value

Comment: Then you should design the first class to accept an interface.  If your first class is calling a final class, that's it, you can't change it.

Comment: No i can't change the code. So there is no way to mock that?

Comment: No, there is no way for you to change that unless you change the code. The smallest possible unit under test possible in such a case is `firstclass` **and** `secondclass` as a union.

Answer (score 0):

1. The method `firstclass.firstmethod()` is private method. So try to test this method through public method in which it is getting called.
2. You can mock `SecondClass` and its final method using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(SecondClass.class)` annotations.

Please see below the working code:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SecondClass.class)
public class FirstClassTest{


    @Before
    public void init() {

    }

    @After
    public void clear() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testfirstmethod() throws Exception{

        SecondClass classMock = PowerMockito.mock(SecondClass.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SecondClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(classMock);
        Mockito.doReturn("test").when(classMock).somemethod();

        new FirstClass().firstmethod();
    }
}
```

**Libraries used:**

[image]